# Is it possible to specify a range of versions for a conflict in a Debian package?

Tags: dependencies, version, debian, conflict

I have a Debian package (lets call it `foo`) that I am splitting into two parts (`foo` and `foo-icons`).  The previous package has three released versions (let's say 1.5, 2.3, and 3.1).  The new package being split out will be common across all three versions.  How can I make sure the new package conflicts with the proper versions of the old?

My problem is two-fold:

1. How do I conflict with a range of versions.  i.e.

   ```
   Conflicts: foo (>= 2.0 & <= 2.3)
   ```
2. How do I conflict with multiple (ranges of) versions to the new `foo-icons` package?

   Logically, what I want is:

   ```
   Conflicts: foo (<= 1.5) & foo (>= 2.0 & <= 2.3) & foo (>= 3.0 & <= 3.1)
   ```

Is any of this possible?  If not, what alternatives do I have?  Do I need to rename my original package (`foo` to `foo1` or somesuch)?

Comment: Related meta question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183051/165502

Answer (score 2):

**1. How do I conflict with a range of versions**

```
Conflicts: foo (>= 2.0), foo (<= 2.3)
```

**2. How do I conflict with multiple (ranges of) versions to the new `foo-icons` package?**

I don't think you can do that, but why don't you increase the version of the splitted `foo` package (eg. 3.2) and `Confict` with `foo (<< 3.2)`?

Furthermore, from the [*Debian Policy Manual*](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-conflicts):

*A `Conflicts` entry may have an "earlier than" version clause if the reason for the conflict is corrected in a later version of one of the packages. However, normally the presence of an "earlier than" version clause is a sign that `Breaks` should have been used instead. An "earlier than" version clause in `Conflicts` prevents dpkg from upgrading or installing the package which declares such a conflict until the upgrade or removal of the conflicted-with package has been completed, which is a strong restriction.*

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The conditions from the `Conflicts` field are applied individually. With what you write, the package would conflict with *all* versions of `foo` (everything greater than 2.0 and everything less than 2.3).